# Can I call an Apex class in HTML email templates?

Tags: apex, email, email-template

I've written an Apex class that returns a string. How can I call it in an HTML email template in Salesforce?

```
<h1>${!CommaSeparation.separate(Lead.Credit__c, 0)}</h1>
```

The function works fine, it returns blank in the email template though. Any help?

Comment: I think you need to use visualforce email template

Comment: Yeah, I am. It all works fine, just the result of my function (above) returns blank *in* that template.

Comment: you need to call the `CommaSeparation.separate(Lead.Credit__c, 0)` this in apex class and store into a variable and then display in component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call the `CommaSeparation.separate(Lead.Credit__c, 0)` this in apex class and store into a variable and then display in component